# Custom meta search engine (search aggregator, federation) for all my favorite tweets, pinboard bookmarks, google plus posts, etc

Tags: search, bookmarks, facebook, twitter, google-plus

I have basically created a curated internet through all my bookmarks on pinboard (previously on delicious); my favorited, retweeted, and personal tweets on twitter; my posts on google plus and facebook; etc. Now I want a way to search them all at once (sort of like https://superuser.com/questions/282714/how-to-create-a-personal-search-engine, but I don't care for local file indexing).

**Is there a single service or recommended set of services that make this easy and work well?**

Specifically, in this priority, I'd want:

- http://Pinboard.in
- Twitter, first from my tweets/retweets/favorites, but then possibly tweets from those I follow
- Evernote (my stuff)
- Google plus (my stuff, then maybe from ppl I follow)
- Facebook  (my stuff, then maybe from friends)

I've tried google custom search engine with just my public URLs (https://twitter.com/pckujawa, https://pinboard.in/u:patku) and, with a few settings (image), it's working ok, but it doesn't seem to be indexing everything I want and definitely isn't letting me set priority of the sources.
[image: pinboard settings for google cse]

[Favs](http://favsapp.com) sounds very promising (description below), but it's only for Mac. I'd like a web-based solution best.

> If you are using social networks, you are also creating favorites. On
>   Facebook you ‘like’, on Twitter and Google Reader you ‘star’, on
>   Delicious and Pinboard you ‘bookmark’ and so on.
>
> Find Favorites
>
> Instead of spreading your favorites across different networks, use
>   Favs to sync them to your Mac. Don't waste any more time on searching
>   for your favorite content - Favs has a powerful search feature build
>   right into the application that makes finding what you like a breeze.
>
> Follow Favorites
>
> Many favorites are public, for example on Twitter. This allows you to
>   follow the favorites of persons you like and just see their
>   hand-picked articles. For those sources Favs marks new entries as
>   ‘unread’ and you can use Favs as a sophisticated Reader app.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a mashup, which aggregates content from many sources and lets you filter it. You can do it using [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/).

First, convert all your sources to XML or RSS feeds. Pinboard provides an RSS feed: https://feeds.pinboard.in/rss/u:patku/ but for Twitter you have to use [RSS 4 Twitter](http://www.rssitfor.me). For other sources you can use the fantastic [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).

Then, create a new pipe, combine all your sources into a single feed, add a user input for a query and filter this feed.

Finally, output the filtered feed as a widget. Done!